# How can extend customer / Shop User registration with sylius 1.10?

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I try to add field to customer / Shop User registration for sylius api to the path /shop/customers.

I extends Customer Model :

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Entity\Customer;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Sylius\Component\Core\Model\Customer as BaseCustomer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="sylius_customer")
 */
class Customer extends BaseCustomer
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=14)
     * @Groups({"shop:customer:create"})
     */
    private $siret;

    public function getSiret(): ?string
    {
        return $this->siret;
    }

    public function setSiret(string $siret): self
    {
        $this->siret = $siret;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

And extends Sylius\Bundle\ApiBundle\Command\RegisterShopUser :

```
    <?php


namespace App\Controller\ShopAPI\Commands;


use Sylius\Bundle\ApiBundle\Command\RegisterShopUser;

class UserRegistrationCommand extends RegisterShopUser
{
    protected string $siret;

    public function __construct(
        string $email,
        string $plainPassword,
        string $firstName,
        string $lastName,
        string $channelCode,
        ?bool $subscribedToNewsletter,
        ?string $phoneNumber,
        string $siret
    )
    {
        parent::__construct(
            $email,
            $plainPassword,
            $firstName,
            $lastName,
            $channelCode,
            $subscribedToNewsletter,
            $phoneNumber
        );
        $this->siret = $siret;
    }

    public function siret(): string
    {
        return $this->siret;
    }

    public static function fromHttpRequestAndChannel(Request $request, ChannelInterface $channel): ChannelBasedRequestInterface
    {
        return new self($request, $channel->getCode());
    }
}
```

I add to the services.yaml :

```
App\Controller\ShopAPI\Commands\UserRegistrationCommand:
    arguments:
        $siret: "%siret%"
```

But when i post with Postman a json with the new field (siret) i have an error 500 with Integrity constraint violation The 'siret' field cannot be empty (null).

I have been looking for the solution for several days but cannot find one.

If anyone can direct me please.

Comment: Where is the value of `siret` set? Is it a .env variable or what?

Comment: It's a new property of Customer

Comment: I'm talking about your reference to `"%siret%"` where is that refenced value defined? Because it appears to be empty (null), or maybe not defined.

Comment: At the beginning I was inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65405576/how-to-overide-the-user-registration-on-the-sylius-shop-api-plugin.
But it's with sylius 1.8.6 with ShopApiBundle and with sylius 1.10 it's ApiBundle

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to allow the field to be `null` ...

1. You need to allow a null value in the database, update the column annotation as follows:

`* @ORM\Column(type="string", length=14, nullable=true)`

2. In `UserRegistrationCommand::__construct` and `Customer::setSiret` change the argument type declarations to nullable:

`?string $siret`

3. Update the database schema `symfony console doctrine:schema:update --force`

Comment: Thanks but I don't want this field to be null, besides it exists in my json

Answer (score 0):

I thought it was just necessary to add Customer.xml :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhS4o.png)

with :

```
<collectionOperations>
            <collectionOperation name="shop_post">
                <attribute name="method">POST</attribute>
                <attribute name="path">/shop/customers</attribute>
                <attribute name="openapi_context">
                    <attribute name="summary">Registers a new customer</attribute>
                </attribute>
                <attribute name="denormalization_context">
                    <attribute name="groups">shop:customer:create</attribute>
                </attribute>
                <attribute name="messenger">input</attribute>
                <attribute name="input">App\Command\RegisterShopUser</attribute>
                <attribute name="output">false</attribute>
            </collectionOperation>
        </collectionOperations>
```

and extends Sylius\Bundle\ApiBundle\Command\RegisterShopUser :

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);



namespace App\Command;

use Sylius\Bundle\ApiBundle\Command\RegisterShopUser as BaseRegisterShopUser;



/**

 * @experimental

 */

class RegisterShopUser extends BaseRegisterShopUser

{

    /**

     * @var int

     * @psalm-immutable

     */

    public $siret;



    public function __construct(

        int $siret

    ) {

        $this->siret = $siret;

    }

}
```

I certainly forgot a step...